# gem yank (<3.1.0) returns "You have enabled multifactor authentication but no OTP code provided" but you can't provide one on the command line

Tags: rubygems, bundler, yank

error:

```
You have enabled multifactor authentication but no OTP code provided. Please fill in an retry.
```

this happens if your Gem is < 3.9.0 and you try to yank

[image]

As you can see, if you provide the option --opt, it still doesn't work, because it tells you that --otp is an invalid option

```
invalid option: --otp=112914
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens if your gem version is < 3.1.0

it has been fixed in rubygems 3.1.0

note that as it is a self-updating binary, the way to update it is with

```
gem update --system
```

to check your version use

```
gem -v
```

This is a known-issue has been fixed in Gem version 3.1.0

if you have gem < 3.1.0 and for some reason, you can't update, there is no work-around. The counter-intuitive thing here is that for the gem push with OTP, if you fail to specify an OTP you get a little interactive OTP input on the command line. Confusingly, if you suffer from this problem, gem yank tells you you didn't supply an OTP and also tells you that `--otp` isn't a valid option.